# select boxes design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

For some reason the `select` rails tag results in a very ugly grey select box. I've been looking around for a way to change this, I'm guessing some sort of default CSS is generated for select boxes by rails but since I have deleted the default stylesheet that rails builds I have no idea where these settings would be set from.

How can I change this ugly default style?

What is the default CSS for a select (outside of ruby)?

EDIT: Turns out the problem is that I"m running it on VirtualBox Linux and the default select box there is the problem.

Comment: You don't need to put "Ruby on Rails (3)" in the title. Please use the ruby-on-rails-3 tag for this instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the browser default?

Adding select { } to your stylesheet and then customizing it with your own rules will cover all the  tags without adding a class to every select box you create. Not that that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just override select in one of your CSS files?

css:
.select { … }

view:
<%= select(…, :class => "whatever") %>

Take a look in /railsproject/public/stylesheets.

Comment: Checked there, only my css is there. I don't want to add a class to everyone of my select boxes so that not a good solution. I would anyways like to know where the new style is declared.

Comment: Then make .select {…} in your CSS, overriding all of them, which negates the need  to do :class => "whatever".

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent on your operating system, and CSS gives you very little control of how it looks. If you are using jQuery, you could use a plugin such as [this](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/).